# Why I get a "type-punned" warning even when using a `char *`?

Tags: gcc, strict-aliasing

gcc (6.3.1 20170109) when compiling the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char x[] = {0x66, 0x19};
    printf("%i\n", ((short *)((char *)&x[0]))[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

generates as warning:

> pun.c: In function ‘main’:
>   pun.c:5:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]

Shouldn't type aliasing allowed when using `char` pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s what C11 (or at least the free draft N1570) has to say about aliasing:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>     object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>     effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>     members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

The character type exception means you can access any type via a `char*` or `unsigned char*`, but it doesn’t mean you can access a `char*` via any type. `short*` doesn’t meet the other criteria listed here for `char*`, so this use is undefined behaviour.

Plus, you could break alignment requirements if that were allowed unconditionally:

```
short x[] = {1, 2};
char* alias = x;
printf("%i\n", *(short*)&alias[1]);
```