# Is it always undefined behaviour to copy the bits of a variable through an incompatible pointer?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing, type-punning

For example, can this

```
unsigned f(float x) {
    unsigned u = *(unsigned *)&x;
    return u;
}
```

cause unpredictable results on a platform where,

- `unsigned` and `float` are both 32-bit
- a pointer has a fixed size for all types
- `unsigned` and `float` can be stored to and loaded from the same part of memory.

I know about strict aliasing rules, but most examples showing problematic cases of violating strict aliasing is like the following.

```
static int g(int *i, float *f) {
    *i = 1;
    *f = 0;
    return *i;
}

int h() {
    int n;
    return g(&n, (float *)&n);
}
```

In my understanding, the compiler is free to assume that `i` and `f` are implicitly `restrict`. The return value of `h` could be `1` if the compiler thinks `*f = 0;` is redundant (because `i` and `f` can't alias), or it could be `0` if it puts into account that the values of `i` and `f` are the same. This is undefined behaviour, so technically, anything else can happen.

However, the first example is a bit different.

```
unsigned f(float x) {
    unsigned u = *(unsigned *)&x;
    return u;
}
```

Sorry for my unclear wording, but everything is done "in-place". I can't think of any other way the compiler might interpret the line `unsigned u = *(unsigned *)&x;`, other than "copy the bits of `x` to `u`".

In practice, all compilers for various architectures I tested in https://godbolt.org/ with full optimization produce the same result for the first example, and varying results (either `0` or `1`) for the second example.

I know it's technically possible that `unsigned` and `float` have different sizes and alignment requirements, or should be stored in different memory segments. In that case even the first code won't make sense. But on most modern platforms where the following holds, is the first example still undefined behaviour (can it produce unpredictable results)?

- `unsigned` and `float` are both 32-bit
- a pointer has a fixed size for all types
- `unsigned` and `float` can be stored to and loaded from the same part of memory.

---

In real code, I do write

```
unsigned f(float x) {
    unsigned u;
    memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof(x));
    return u;
}
```

The compiled result is the same as using pointer casting, after optimization. This question is about interpretation of the standard about strict aliasing rules for code such as the first example.

Comment: You write to x (copy) using type float, you read x using type unsigned int => aliasing violation. Problems are less likely for this case, but it is still illegal.

Comment: duplicates: [If this is undefined behavior then why is it given as a seemingly legitimate example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64562736/995714), [Why I get a "type-punned" warning even when using a `char *`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42084824/995714), [Why is type punning considered UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63422076/995714), [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848/995714). Different types may lies in different domains (float vs integer) or even different memory spaces so it's forbidden. The only valid way in C is to use a `union`

Comment: The standard doesn't specify different rules for different aliasing cases, so the above examples all have aliasing and have UB

Comment: Undefined behaviour is something specified by the Standard. The fact that it (always) produces the same/desired result in a specific case, on a specific platform, does not make it any less undefined (by the Standard).

Comment: Undefined Behavior does not mean unpredictable result. It is just not defined by the standard.

Comment: @AdrianMole: The question is not predicated upon the behavior in a specific case. It asks whether there is any case in a practical compiler where the aliasing would not be performed as the nominal meaning of the code indicates, in spite of the standard’s aliasing rules. The title needs to be reworded, but the actual question is not about whether the behavior is defined by the C standard or not. The question is about whether rational compiler design would lead to a failure of the no inal aliasing.

Comment: ` This question is about interpretation of the standard` What is unclear to you?

Comment: Your godbolt link forgot to link the actual code and compilers you tried.  https://godbolt.org/z/rvj3d4e4o shows GCC4.1, from before GCC went out of its way to support "obvious" cases like this, to sometimes not break people's buggy code using this compact but UB idiom.  It loads garbage from stack memory, unless you use `-fno-strict-aliasing` to make it `movd` to that location first. It also warns `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's kind of surprising to me. I personally think the strict aliasing rules are the most counter-intuitive in a low-level language like C, especially on architectures like x86 where any data can be stored anywhere in (accessible) memory. Is there actual cases where strict aliasing helps better code generation, in which the same cannot be achieved with `restrict`?

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Is the question about a rational compiler design which makes a bona fide effort to avoid braeking useful programs, or about free compilers like gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it always undefined behaviour to copy the bits of a variable through an incompatible pointer?

Yes.

The rule is [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) :

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
> the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

The effective type of the object `x` is `float` - it is defined with that type.

- `unsigned` is not compatible with `float`,
- `unsigned` is not a qualified version of `float`,
- `unsigned` is not a signed or unsigned type of `float`,
- `unsigned` is not a signed or unsigned type corresponding to qualified version of `float`,
- `unsigned` is not an aggregate or union type
- and `unsigned` is not a character type.

The "shall" is violated, it is undefined behavior (see [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2) ). There is no other interpretation.

We also have [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) :

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> - An object has its stored value accessed other than by an lvalue of an allowable type (6.5).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The standard is a logical and concise piece of document, but it's sometimes too concise that it is hard to find where the information is, or often the important supplementary sentences are scattered many pages away.

Comment: `logical and concise` Och, you are overrating it.

Comment: @KamilCuk: What the Standard "isn't" is *complete*.  Many constructs are left undefined because implementations were expected to process them consistently, with or without a mandate, in the absence of any compelling reason to do otherwise, but the authors of the Standard didn't want to try to guess what reasons implementations might have for deviating from the commonplace behavior.

Comment: Is there anything in the Standard that would require a compiler, given `struct foo {uint32_t x[10];} s;` to regard the lvalue expression `s.x[4]` as having any association with type `struct foo`, but would not require a compiler given `*(uint32_t*)floatPtr` to recognize it as being associated with type `uint32_t`?  The former expression is *defined* as meaning `(*((s.x)+(4)))`, which applies the `*` operator to a pointer of type `uint32_t*`, yielding an lvalue of type `uint32_t` which not among the types that may be used to access a `struct foo`.  A compiler that isn't deliberately blind...

Comment: ...would of course notice that the pointer was freshly formed in a manner that involved type `struct foo`, but a compiler that wasn't being deliberately blind should be equally capable of recognizing that `*(uint32_t*)floatPtr` dereferences a pointer that's freshly formed in a manner involving type `float`.

Answer (score 2):

As Kamil explains, it's UB.  Even `int` and `long` (or `long` and `long long`) aren't alias-compatible even when they're the same size.  (But interestingly, `unsigned int` is compatible with `int`)

It's nothing to do with being the same size, or using the same register-set as suggested in a comment, it's mainly a way to let compilers assume that different pointers don't point to overlapping memory when optimizing.  They still have to support C99 `union` type-punning, not just `memcpy`.  So for example a `dst[i] = src[i]` loop doesn't need to check for possible overlap when unrolling or vectorizing, if dst and src have different types.<sup>1</sup>

If you're accessing the same integer data, the standard requires that you use the exact same type, modulo only things like `signed` vs. `unsigned` and `const`.  Or that you use (unsigned) `char*`, which is like GNU C `__attribute__((may_alias))`.

---

**The other part of your question seems to be why it appears to work in practice, despite the UB.**
Your godbolt link forgot to link the actual compilers you tried.

https://godbolt.org/z/rvj3d4e4o shows GCC4.1, from **before GCC went out of its way to support "obvious" local compile-time-visible cases like this**, to sometimes not break people's buggy code using non-portable idioms like this.
It loads garbage from stack memory, unless you use `-fno-strict-aliasing` to make it `movd` to that location first.  (Store/reload instead of `movd %xmm0, %eax` is a missed-optimization bug that's been fixed in later GCC versions for most cases.)

```
f:     # GCC4.1 -O3
        movl    -4(%rsp), %eax
        ret
```

```
f:    # GCC4.1 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing
        movss   %xmm0, -4(%rsp)
        movl    -4(%rsp), %eax
        ret
```

Even that old GCC version warns `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules` which should make it obvious that GCC notices this and does *not* consider it well-defined.   Later GCC that do choose to support this code still warn.

It's debatable whether it's better to sometimes work in simple cases, but break other times, vs. always failing.  But given that GCC `-Wall` does still warn about it, that's probably a good tradeoff between convenience for people dealing with legacy code or porting from MSVC.  Another option would be to always break it unless people use `-fno-strict-aliasing`, which they should if dealing with codebases that depend on this behaviour.

---

#### Being UB doesn't mean required-to-fail

Just the opposite; it would take tons of extra work to actually trap on every signed overflow in the C abstract machine, for example, especially when optimizing stuff like `2 + c - 3` into `c - 1`.  That's what `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` tries to do, adding x86 `jo` instructions after additions (except it still does constant-propagation so it's just adding `-1`, not detecting temporary overflow on INT_MAX. https://godbolt.org/z/WM9jGT3ac). And it seems strict-aliasing is not one of the kinds of UB it tries to detect at run time.

See also the clang blog article: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

---

##### An implementation *is* free to define behaviour the ISO C standard leaves undefined

For example, MSVC always defines this aliasing behaviour, like GCC/clang/ICC do with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.  Of course, that doesn't change the fact that pure ISO C leaves it undefined.

It just means that on *those* specific C implementations, the code is guaranteed to work the way you want, rather than happening to do so by chance or by de-facto compiler behaviour if it's simple enough for modern GCC to recognize and do the more "friendly" thing.

Just like `gcc -fwrapv` for signed-integer overflows.

---

###### Footnote 1: example of strict-aliasing helping code-gen

```
#define QUALIFIER // restrict

void convert(float *QUALIFIER pf, const int *pi) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<10240 ; i++){
        pf[i] = pi[i];
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyagA%2BudTkVjVEQJDqzTAGF09AK5smBpwBkCTNgAcp4ARtikIABM5AAO6ErE9kyuHl4G8Yl2Qv6BIWzhkTHW2LbJIkQspESpnt48Vtg22UwVVUS5wWER0VaV1bXpDUr9HQFdBT1RAJRW6O6kqJxcAKRRAMw4dIEA1ACKCgCCvgCSAGInuABKOwD0tzuk2COkBLYrWocfhwBu6ASYHYYJg/CJEWj0dAsIg7ABUB2O50uN1iNHIQKEIx2ARhsNiBGmOxWAHYAELfHaUnaCUgQHHYlbrAAiWiJ61JDPWzh4Wii0lZjI5BDW5KipOmJPJnypMp2qJWAFZScKFUy2Wr8YrlYqmYKKVSSbrPobvlxZvRuAr%2BN4uDpyOhuM4dkp5otsESNnxyERtGbZgBrEDrYkAOgAHMStABOaQK6TEqMANmkPBkhm40n4bBACq05BtdodXH4ShAeZ9trN5DgsBQ8yIsXcREo1AwbHxjCK5GwhBIkQagmEYgknDTg8UKg0vu9T2WXoA7qQWLFuHxzZbrdOiwB5JuNmHoGg7dRhxMAWmTO2AqFQO1TIaiOwgrnbDAiHvWM34FZ001mSGwFgcEiCB1y4TNyGzXN8y3bgSzLb1fT/chA3WBUQ2JHlYx4RMFT5MMtFw9MuHWTdK3tODEMrWYa2QNB0FfTsWwgNsOx6VBgFTGI6HoIgIlLCBQmnUIAiqABPVd%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%2Bpmlp5rGPIRumybc9L9p0/7HbXX2hpDuO4jToxiiuEui9pCvG87x4B8n2cR7exetZ1jej7ide6ZvyQ4H1nWEM58Xpfl%2BRsjC0o0sceosCoizKQtHR2Di1%2Bv1yFBenkhAaQgA) shows that with the `-O3` defaults for GCC11.2 for x86-64, we get *just* a SIMD loop with `movdqu` / `cvtdq2ps` / `movups` and loop overhead.  With `-O3 -fno-strict-aliasing`, we get two versions of the loop, and an overlap check to see if we can run the scalar or the SIMD version.

> Is there actual cases where strict aliasing helps better code generation, in which the same cannot be achieved with `restrict`

You might well have a pointer that might point into either of two `int` arrays, but definitely not at any `float` variable, so you can't use `restrict` on it.  Strict-aliasing will let the compiler still avoid spill/reload of `float` objects around stores through the pointer, even if the `float` objects are global vars or otherwise aren't provably local to the function. (Escape analysis.)

Or a `struct node *` that definitely isn't the same type as the payload in a tree.

Also, most code *doesn't* use `restrict` all over the place.  It could get quite cumbersome.  Not just in loops, but in every function that deals with pointers to structs.  And if you get it wrong and promise something that's not true, your code's broken.

Comment: The other answer answered my original question, but thanks for explaining the reason behind the rules. I can see now that it can save some load/stores in complex code where there are a lot of different `structs` all over.

Comment: Not only are a 64-bit `long` and 64-bit `long long` not alias-compatible, but in the dialect processed by gcc, the existence of code which would *if executed* access a `long` using a `long long*` is sufficient to cause nonsensical behavior *even if the code in question never actually executes*.

Comment: Most code could and should use `restrict` if the Standard were to recognize it as a transitive directed relation rather than a weird context-sensitive equivalence relation in which the value of `p` used in a statement like `if (flag) {*p = 3;}` may not be "based upon" the value of `p` in the enclosing block.

Answer (score 2):

The Standard was never intended to fully, accurately, and unambiguously partition programs that have defined behavior and those that don't(*), but instead relies upon compiler writers to exercise a certain amount of common sense.

(*) If it was intended for that purpose, it fails miserably, as evidenced by the amount of confusion stemming from it.

Consider the following two code snippets:

```
/* Assume suitable declarations of u are available everywhere */
union test { uint32_t ww[4]; float ff[4]; } u;

/* Snippet #1 */
uint32_t proc1(int i, int j)
{
  u.ww[i] = 1;
  u.ff[j] = 2.0f;
  return u.ww[i];
}

/* Snippet #2, part 1, in one compilation unit */
uint32_t proc2a(uint32_t *p1, float *p2)
{
  *p1 = 1;
  *p2 = 2.0f;
  return *p1;
}

/* Snippet #2, part 2, in another compilation unit */
uint32_t proc2(int i, int j)
{
  return proc2a(u.ww+i, u.ff+j);
}
```

It is clear that the authors of the Standard intended that the first version of the code be processed meaningfully on platforms where that would make sense, but it's also clear that at least some of the authors of C99 and later versions did not intend to require that the second version be processed likewise (some of the authors of C89 may have intended that the "strict aliasing rule" only apply to situations where a *directly named* object would be accessed via pointer of another type, as shown in the example given in the published Rationale; nothing in the Rationale suggests a desire to apply it more broadly).

On the other hand, the Standard *defines* the [] operator in such a fashion that `proc1` is semantically equivalent to:

```
uint32_t proc3(int i, int j)
{
  *(u.ww+i) = 1;
  *(u.ff+j) = 2.0f;
  return *(u.ww+i);
}
```

and there's nothing in the Standard that would imply that proc() shouldn't have the same semantics.  What gcc and clang seem to do is special-case the `[]` operator as having a different meaning from pointer dereferencing, but nothing in the Standard makes such a distinction.  The only way to consistently interpret the Standard is to recognize that the form with `[]` falls in the category of actions which the Standard doesn't require that implementations process meaningfully, but relies upon them to handle anyway.

Constructs such as yours example of using a directly-cast pointer to access storage associated with an object of the original pointer's type fall in a similar category of constructs which at least some authors of the Standard likely expected (and would have demanded, if they didn't expect) that compilers would handle reliably, with or without a mandate, since there was no imaginable reason why a quality compiler would do otherwise.  Since then, however, clang and gcc have evolved to defy such expectations.  Even if clang and gcc would normally generate useful machine code for a function, they seek to perform aggressive inter-procedural optimizations that make it impossible to predict what constructs will be 100% reliable.  Unlike some compilers which refrain from applying potential optimizing transforms unless they can prove that they are sound, clang and gcc seek to perform transforms that can't be proven to affect program behavior.

Comment: Why are you assigning `2.0f` to part of `uint16_t ff[4]`?  I was expecting that union member to be a float array.  Also, wouldn't that stop `u.ff+j` from being a valid `float*` arg for `proc2a`?  So I'm guessing you started with two sizes of int, then changed to float but forgot the union.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'd been dithering between using `uint16_t[4]` and `uint32_t[4]` (to allow manipulating upper or lower half of a word separately), or between using `uint32_t[4]` and `float[4]`, but I sorta must have left a mix-and-match mess.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Though accessing `float` values as `uint16_t` could still be somewhat useful on a few platforms like the 68000, if one wants to e.g. extract just he exponent part of a `float`.  More important than the particulars of the example, however, is the principle that if the "strict aliasing rules" were omitted from the Standard, the behavior would be defined on platforms that define the values of all possible bit patterns, and in cases where a behavior would generally be defined but for optimization purposes it might be useful to allow corner-case behaviors to differ...

Comment: ...the Standard is intended to treat most questions of what corner cases to support as a "quality of implementation" issue outside its jurisdiction, but the authors of C89 unfortunately went out of their way to avoid any suggestion that some implementations might be "better" than others.